# Building/Installing Required a52 Plugin

Tags: 12.04

I am trying to compile and install the a52 plugin following the instructions from here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DigitalAC-3Pulseaudio

This worked on Ubuntu 11.10 but gives me some errors when I try to compile the plugin on Ubuntu 12.04. I've searched for a solution however I couldn't find much on this topic in general, not to talk about a solution. I would really appreciate some help on this:

```
bogdan@bogdan-desktop:~$ cd ~/tmp/
bogdan@bogdan-desktop:~/tmp$ cd alsa-plugins-1.0.25/
bogdan@bogdan-desktop:~/tmp/alsa-plugins-1.0.25$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/bogdan/tmp/alsa-plugins-1.0.25'
Making all in oss
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/bogdan/tmp/alsa-plugins-1.0.25/oss'
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -Wall -g -I/usr/include/alsa   -g -O2 -MT ctl_oss.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/ctl_oss.Tpo -c -o ctl_oss.lo ctl_oss.c
../libtool: line 831: X--tag=CC: command not found
../libtool: line 864: libtool: ignoring unknown tag : command not found
../libtool: line 831: X--mode=compile: command not found
../libtool: line 997: *** Warning: inferring the mode of operation is deprecated.: command not found
../libtool: line 998: *** Future versions of Libtool will require --mode=MODE be specified.: command not found
../libtool: line 1141: Xgcc: command not found
../libtool: line 1141: X-DHAVE_CONFIG_H: command not found
../libtool: line 1141: X-I.: command not found
../libtool: line 1141: X-I..: command not found
../libtool: line 1141: X-Wall: command not found
../libtool: line 1141: X-g: command not found
../libtool: line 1141: X-I/usr/include/alsa: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1141: X-g: command not found
../libtool: line 1141: X-O2: command not found
../libtool: line 1141: X-MT: command not found
../libtool: line 1141: Xctl_oss.lo: command not found
../libtool: line 1141: X-MD: command not found
../libtool: line 1141: X-MP: command not found
../libtool: line 1141: X-MF: command not found
../libtool: line 1141: X.deps/ctl_oss.Tpo: No such file or directory
../libtool: line 1141: X-c: command not found
../libtool: line 1192: Xctl_oss.lo: command not found
../libtool: line 1197: libtool: compile: cannot determine name of library object from `': command not found
make[2]: *** [ctl_oss.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/bogdan/tmp/alsa-plugins-1.0.25/oss'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bogdan/tmp/alsa-plugins-1.0.25'
make: *** [all] Error 2
bogdan@bogdan-desktop:~/tmp/alsa-plugins-1.0.25$
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to this problem!

The solution:

```
libtoolize --force --copy; aclocal; autoconf; automake; make
```

(source: http://geeklymusings.blogspot.ro/2009/04/libtool-problems-on-ubuntu.html )